# Chromecast youtube video on Android

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast, android-youtube-api

I am developing an Android application which can play youtube videos. The youtube videos are played inside application using Youtube Player API https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Please let me know if there is any option to Chromecast Videos directly without using Google Cast SDK?

Thanks

Comment: If you can determine a URL that will be an MP4 representation of the video, you should be able to use that with `RemotePlaybackClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to do that.

Comment: Hello, do you mean there's no any supported way to cast YouTube video from an app that's not official YouTube, even using Google Cast SDK?

Comment: Yes, currently that is the case.